# Is this short proof correct? distance between sets

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, compactness

For every pair of sets $K, L \subseteq \mathbb R$ we define the distance between them as $d(K,L) = \inf \{|x-y|, x \in K, y \in L\}$

We are asked to prove that if $K$ is closed and $L$ is compact and $K \cap L = \emptyset$ then $d(K,L) > 0$.

**What I tried:**

define $f: L \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = \inf \{|x-y|, y \in K\}$

It follows from the definition that $d(K,L) = \min _{x \in L} f(x)$. Furthermore, since $L$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, we know that $f$ actually attains the value.

Now suppose $d(K,L) = 0$. Since $f$ actually attains that value somewhere, there is $x_0 \in L$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$.

So either $\exists y_0 \in K$ such that $|x_0-y_0| = 0$, which makes no sense since the intersection is empty, or there is a sequence $\{y_k\} \in K$ whos limit is $x_0$.

But since $K$ is closed, this means that $x_0 \in K$, since a closed set contains all of its limit points, so again we arrive at a contradiction.

Is this correct and clear enough?

Comment: Seems correct. Also, the case $ \exists y_0 \in K$... is a particular case of the existence of a sequence in $K$ converging to $x_0$, so it can be avoided.

Comment: It's fine except  one detail:  $\min$ should be   $\inf$ in the sentence "It follows from the definition that $d(K,L)=\min_{x\in L}f(x).\;$"  The existence of $\min f$ is justified in the  $next$  sentence.... BTW: It can be shortened: If $f(x_0)=0$ then there is a sequence $(y_n)_n$  in $K$ with $|x_0-y_n|\to f(x_0)=0,$ implying $x_0\in \overline K=K,$ a contradiction,. Therefore $d(K,L)=f(x_0)>0.$ That is, the first case (  a possible $y_0$) is actually included in the second case.... And I can't resist pointing out we must assume that $K$ and $L$  are not empty .